# Mocking in GWT application showcase with the help of GIN

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, mocking, mvp, gwt-gin

I need an example of well-structured full-stack GWT application written in the best practices: with MVP pattern usage, GIN modules (at least 2: production module and the mocking one for tests), JRE light-weight tests (extending TestCase class). The primary goal of this request is to find out how GWT app should be effectively tested with the help of GIN.

This showcase doesn't need to be huge. Several simple tests for one presenter would be enough. I have already took a look at "Contacts" example provided by Google - but it doesn't use GIN library.

Thanks a lot for any advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apache Hupa project http://james.apache.org/hupa/ build with GWT uses Gin/Guice, mocking and the MVP pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link:
http://www.aceevo.com/
It does use GIN, but for me it covers a big spectrum of things to consider.

I'm still working on the whole MVP thingy trying to put everything together.
However, there are some tweaks before this example is runnable. If you someone thinks it's worth it I would post those tweaks.

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting project. I have looked through all of the posts, but it does not contain any notice about unit-testing.